# Why does the C library use macros and functions with same name?

Tags: c, naming, functions, macros

I am reading 'The Standard C Library' by PJ Plauger which is really interesting. The book  explains not only how to USE the library but also how it is implemented.

I have finished reading the `ctype.h` section and in the header the functions are declared as both macros AND functions. For example

```
int isdigit(int);
```

but also

```
#define isdigit(c) (_Ctype[(int)(c)] & _DI)
```

I don't understand why BOTH are used?

Also, if I try to recreate my own custom `ctype` header and implementation, I can only compile successfully if I remove the macro (comment out the define).

This aspect was not really explained in the book. Can someone please explain?

Comment: There is nothing in the C standard forcing a compiler to implement it as a macro. The macro is most likely a residue from the old days when C didn't have inlining. Though a smart compiler should be able to inline that function if needed, without an explicit inline keyword. So the function-like macro is only there because the compiler was implemented by someone who was not brilliant at making compilers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The macro is (putatively) more efficient, as it doesn't involve a function call.  It can be optimised more easily, as it just involves a pointer offset lookup.

The function call allows linking against the same library even if the program was compiled without the macro definition - if it was compiled with a different header, or just with a rogue declaration inside the source file. Should, for example, you have a compiler which has someone's "improved" version of ctype.h that *didn't* have the macro, the function would still exist at runtime for use.

If we look at the standard:

> [c99](/questions/tagged/c99)
>
> #### 7.1.4 Use of library functions
>
> Any function
>   declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro deﬁned in the header, so if a library function is declared explicitly when its header is included, one
>   of the techniques shown below can be used to ensure the declaration is not affected by
>   such a macro. Any macro deﬁnition of a function can be suppressed locally by enclosing
>   the name of the function in parentheses, because the name is then not followed by the left
>   parenthesis that indicates expansion of a macro function name. For the same syntactic
>   reason, it is permitted to take the address of a library function even if it is also deﬁned as a macro.

That means that if you write:

```
int b = (isdigit)(c);
```

or

```
int (*f)(int) = &isdigit;
int b = f(c);
```

then you are invoking the actual function, not the macro.  You can also legally write:

```
#undef isdigit
int b = isdigit(c);
```

or (in a source file not having `#include <ctype.h>` directly or transitively):

```
extern int isdigit(int);
int b = isdigit(c);
```

Comment: How could the program be compiled WITHOUT the macro definition?

Comment: @user619818 using `extern int isdigit(int)`, for example.

Comment: Just so I am clear, you mean user has no #include <whatever> but instead adds int isdigit(int); at top of implementation file.  OK, just read through your response properly.

Comment: Having a callable function (vs. inlined macro code) also allows other languages like python and perl to interface with those functions